# How to report "sed" in-place changes

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace

When using `sed` to replace strings in-place, is there a way to make it report the changes it does (without relying on a diff of old and new files)?

For instance, how can I change the command line

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/abc/def/g'
```

so I can see the changes that are made on the fly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `sed`'s `w` flag with either `/dev/stderr`, `/dev/tty`, `/dev/fd/2` if supported on your system. E.g. with an input `file` like:

```
foo first
second: missing
third: foo
none here
```

running

```
sed -i '/foo/{
s//bar/g
w /dev/stdout
}' file
```

outputs:

```
bar first
third: bar
```

though `file` content was changed to:

```
bar first
second: missing
third: bar
none here
```

So in your case, running:

```
find . -type f -printf '\n%p:\n' -exec sed -i '/foo/{
s//bar/g
w /dev/fd/2
}' {} \;
```

will edit the files in-place and output:

```
./file1:
bar stuff
more bar

./file2:

./file3:
bar first
third: bar
```

You could also print something like `original line >>> modified line` e.g.:

```
find . -type f -printf '\n%p:\n' -exec sed -i '/foo/{
h
s//bar/g
H
x
s/\n/ >>> /
w /dev/fd/2
x
}' {} \;
```

edits the files in-place and outputs:

```
./file1:
foo stuff >>> bar stuff
more foo >>> more bar

./file2:

./file3:
foo first >>> bar first
third: foo >>> third: bar
```

Answer (score 21):

You could do it in two passes using the `p`rint action on the first pass with:

```
find . -type f | xargs sed --quiet 's/abc/def/gp'
```

where `--quiet` makes sed not show every line and the `p` suffix shows only lines where the substitution has matched.

This has the limitation that sed will not show *which* files are being changed which of course could be fixed with some additional complexity.

Comment: It doesn't quite do what I wanted since you need two passes, but I'm voting up because I just learned this p thing and it's very useful. Especially if, as you said, the files were also printed. Something like `for x in \`find . -type f\`; do echo ///File $x: ; sed --quiet 's/abc/def/gp' $x; done`

Comment: @msw I have many `sed` expression, I don't want to write `/gp` for each one. How to set it globaly?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that's possible, but a workaround might be to use perl instead:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -i -pe 's/abc/def/ && print STDERR' {} +
```

This will print the **altered** lines to standard error. For example:

```
$ cat foo
fooabcbarabc
blah blah
$ find . -type f -exec perl -i -pe 's/abc/def/ && print STDERR' {} +
foodefbarabc
$ cat foo
foodefbarabc
blah blah
```

You can also make this slightly more complex, printing the line number, file name, original line and changed line:

```
$ find . -type f -exec perl -i -pe ' 
   $was=$_; chomp($was);
   s/abc/def/ && print STDERR "$ARGV($.): $was : $_"
   close ARGV if eof' {} +
./foo(1): fooabcbarabc : foodefbarabc
```

Note the `close ARGV if eof` which is needed for `$.` to be reset between each file.

Add the `g` flag to the `s///` operator to replace all occurrences on each line rather than just the first.

Comment: +1 You can also use `$ARGV` for the name of the file being operated on.

Comment: @JosephR. good point, added.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably helpful (didn't test it myself). I am not selecting as it doesn't use sed, so it doesn't exactly answer the question.

Comment: @ricab that's fine, you should not accept an answer unless it actually _answers_ your question. Bear in mind though that for simple things like this, `perl`'s syntax is very similar to `sed`'s and I don't think what you're asking for is actually possible with `sed`.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible using the **w** flag which writes the current pattern to a file. So by adding it to the substitute command we can report successive substitutions to a file and print it after the job is done. 
I also like to colorize the replaced string with grep.

```
sed -i -e "s/From/To/gw /tmp/sed.done" file_name
grep --color -e "To" /tmp/sed.done
```

Note, that there must be only one space between the **w** and its file name.

This is even better than diff, since diffing might also show changes even if they were not made by sed.

Comment: Just tested it out and sed only writes lines it substituded to `sed.done`. The lines with "To" in the original file are therefore not printed to `sed.done`, thus when you `grep "To" sed.done` you will only see the lines that _are_ changed by `sed`. You won't see the original line in the file _before_ it was substituted, if that's what you're aiming at ...

Answer (score 1):

I like the @terdon solution - perl is good for this.

Here's my tweaked version that:

- won't try to alter files that dont have have the matching string
- will backup the before version of the files that change (create a .bak version)
- will list every file/lineno changed, and
  show the OLD and NEW versions of that line indented and underneath 
  for easy reading

code

```
find /tmp/test -type f ! -name "*.bak" -exec grep -l '/opt/gridmon' {} \; | xargs -L1 perl -ni'.bak' -e'$old=$_; s/\/opt\/gridmon/~/g && print STDERR "$ARGV($.):\n\tOLD:$old\tNEW:$_"'
```

example output

```
/tmp/test/test4.cfg(13):
    OLD:    ENVFILE /opt/gridmon/server/etc/gridmonserver.cfg
    NEW:    ENVFILE ~/server/etc/gridmonserver.cfg
/tmp/test/test4.cfg(24):
    OLD:    ENVFILE /opt/gridmon/server/etc/gridmonserver.cfg
    NEW:    ENVFILE ~/server/etc/gridmonserver.cfg
```