# advanced sed print + replace

Tags: sed

I am interested if there's a more elegant solution to the one posted below.

```
[]$ find ./abc -type f -exec sed -n 's/test/best/pg' {} + ; find ./abc -type f -exec sed -i 's/test/best/g' {} +
```

The first `find sed` command prints all found patterns to console. The second `find sed` command actually substitutes the patterns within file.

The problems I have encountered:

1. `sed -n -i` (cannot have multiple command line modifier/arguments) -? someone confirm?
2. `sed` does not have a native modifier to print results prior to substitution -? had trouble finding a solution, maybe it exists, and the command can be modified (i.e. below will output nothing, and substitute behind your back!).

   ```
   find ./abc -type f -exec sed -i 's/test/best/pg' {} +
   ```

Comment: Maybe `find [...] -exec grep test {}; sed -i 's/test/best/g' {} \;`?

Comment: thanks @don_crissti I'm reading that article and haven't found a good solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @DopeGhoti,  something more elegant, i.e. single command as opposed to using 2 commands.

Comment: That'll be tough, as by design `sed` modifies one stream of input and gives one stream of output; I don't think there's any way to have it take one input and give two outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't need to have two separate *`find` commands:*

```
find abc -type f -exec sed -n 's/test/best/pg' {} + -exec sed -i 's/test/best/g' {} +
```

... and you don't need the `./` in front of `abc`.

Comment: Because that doesn't work.  It's the worst of both worlds — it doesn't print anything, and it deletes all the lines in the file that don't match `test`.

Comment: Oh, god. That's brainless enough I'm just going to delete it.  Here: `sed -ni '/test/w /dev/tty
  s//best/g; p'` (w/ a newline after `tty`)

Comment: Note that jthill edited his/her comment since I posted my first response; the first version was `sed -ni 's/test/best/pg' \{} +`.  The revised version, `sed -ni '/test/{p;s//best/g}' \{} +`, is even worse: it still deletes all the lines in the file that don't match `test`, but *it doesn't even do the requested substitution on the lines that do!*

Comment: `sed -ni '/test/w /dev/tty s//best/g; p'` doesn't work either.  If you think you have an answer, you should *post an answer* rather than critiquing a correct answer; comments are not good for multi-line text.  If you meant to have a newline rather than a space after `/dev/tty`, it ***still doesn't work*** (suggestion: *try* commands before you post them) but is coming close to answers that were posted to [How to report “sed” in-place changes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200576/80216) six months ago.

Comment: You're right, of course. Started out brainless, continued that way.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on GNU/anything you can

```
find abc -type f -exec sed -i 's/test/best/gw /dev/fd/2' {} +
```

but in your text you mentioned wanting to print results prior to substitution, not sure what "results" means there but

```
find abc -type f -exec sed -i '/test/w /dev/fd/2
                               s//best/g' {} +
```

prints the lines that will change prior to substitution.