# Any way to have a "verbose mode" or "debug mode" with sed?

Tags: sed, debugging, gnu

Is there a way to make `gnu sed` be verbose about what is run and what is done ?
I'd like to have something like a "debug mode" so that I can see - for each line of input - the content of the hold space and pattern space before and after the script is run etc.

Comment: Is `l;x;l;x;` at the start & end of the program adequate?

Comment: It looks like GNU `sed` [gained](https://lists.gnu.org/r/sed-devel/2018-07/msg00006.html) a `--debug` [feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_002d_002ddebug) last summer (version 4.6).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As [fra-san](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/315749/fra-san) [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492871/any-way-to-have-a-verbose-mode-or-debug-mode-with-sed/492893#comment905147_492871), GNU `sed` introduced a [`--debug`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#index-_002d_002ddebug) option which does pretty much what you’re looking for, in version 4.6; so e.g if you run:

```
printf '%s\n' one two  | sed --debug 'H;1h;$x;$s/\n/_/g'
```

the output is

```
SED PROGRAM:
  H
  1 h
  $ x
  $ s/\n/_/g
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 1
PATTERN: one
COMMAND: H
HOLD:    \none
COMMAND: 1 h
HOLD:    one
COMMAND: $ x
COMMAND: $ s/\n/_/g
END-OF-CYCLE:
one
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 2
PATTERN: two
COMMAND: H
HOLD:    one\ntwo
COMMAND: 1 h
COMMAND: $ x
PATTERN: one\ntwo
HOLD:    two
COMMAND: $ s/\n/_/g
MATCHED REGEX REGISTERS
  regex[0] = 3-4 '
'
PATTERN: one_two
END-OF-CYCLE:
one_two
```

I don’t know what distribution you use, but this version of sed (or a later one) is available [in Debian 10](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/sed), [in Ubuntu 19.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sed), and derivatives; it will be available in Fedora 33.

Answer (score 2):

I find it a little tricky getting what I personally consider "verbose output" out of sed, by which I mean "what is sed doing".

If you omit a `-i` argument, the resulting edited stream is printed right to the console. Which isn't super helpful if the input file/stream is very long and/or you're making lots of edits or subtle ones.

As Stephen pointed out, the `--debug` option will tell you *everything* sed is doing. Which means it prints every input line, tells you each command it's running on the lines of the file, the result of those commands, and the edited line. So in my experience too verbose. I usually use sed for in-place search and replace. Running a single-regex replacement on a 1450 line file, the output is ~8700 lines. Quite an earful and a lot to peruse. But you can make that a lot more informative with a little creative grepping.

For the case of regex search and replace, the following is really helpful:

```
sed --debug -e 's/pattern/replacement/' file.txt | grep -B 3 -A 4 -P '^MATCHED'
```

The debug output will print a line starting with "MATCHED" every time it matches a regex command, and that's the 4th line of a 8 total per match telling you what sed did. So including `-B 3 -A 4` will print just the groups of lines where sed is actually making a change, and won't print the 8 lines for every input line where nothing changed.

Obviously there are other things you can do with sed besides regex replacement so you'll need to tinker with this to suit your use case and commands, but I feel like this approach allows you to pare down the `--debug` output to something more usable. I.e. kind of what I'd expect from a verbose flag based on other utilities like cp, mv, etc.

Comment: Well, to see the changes when you only  search/replace in a file you don't really need the `gnu sed ` `--debug` feature, you could do it with any `sed`, [as I wrote here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200576/22142)