# Report sed changes + corresponding perl syntax

Tags: linux, sed, perl

Newbie learning Linux and perl:

I would like to (a) search-replace strings, (b) match filename pattern *.myfile.*, (c) look recursively in subdirectories, and (d) print the line number, file name, original line and changed line.

I am looking for the two versions using `sed` and in `perl` syntax. I found a starting point in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97297/how-to-report-sed-in-place-changes) but:

First: sed

Need: Add syntax for pattern matching for *.myfile.*, recursive search, print line number, and get rid of `w /dev/fd/2` --I don't know what it does, I want to print results to terminal, not an output file. Note: I am using Visual Studio terminal on mac OS):

```
find . -type f -printf '\n%p:\n' -exec sed -i '/foo/{
h
s//bar/g
H
x
s/\n/ >>> /
w /dev/fd/2
x
}' {} \;
```

Output:

```
./file1:
foo stuff >>> bar stuff
more foo >>> more bar

./file2:

./file3:
foo first >>> bar first
third: foo >>> third: bar
```

Second: perl:

Need: Add syntax for pattern matching for *.myfile.*, and recursive search. ALSO the line number output by `$.` is wrong. It is correct for the first file, but it keeps counting and doesn't reset as it searches more files (see [image: attached screenshot] for output).

```
$ find . -type f | 
   xargs perl -i -ne '$was=$_; chomp($was);
                      s/abc/def/ && print STDERR "$ARGV($.): $was : $_"' 
./foo(1): fooabcbar : foodefbar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those codes modify files in place (well, would be for the perl one if `-p` was used in place of `-n`;  with `-n`, that results in files being emptied) and at the same time print to stderr (via `w /dev/fd/2` or `print STDERR`) what was modified.

However `find . | xargs` is wrong as the output of `find` is not compatible with the input format expected by `xargs`. Also, in `perl`, `$.` which contains the current input line number is not reset between files unless you close the `ARGV` handle at the  end of each file so it should be:

```
find . -name '*.myfile' -exec perl -i -pe '
  chomp($was = $_);
  print STDERR "$ARGV($.): $was : $_" if s/abc/def/;
  close ARGV if eof' -- {} +
```

For `sed`, not sure macos supports `/dev/fd/2` to mean stderr, but even on Linux-based systems (macos is not Linux btw), using `w /dev/fd/2` would be wrong unless stderr goes to specific types of files such as pipes or terminal devices. `-printf` is specific to the GNU implementation of `find` and is not found in any other implementation including macos'.

Also on macos' `sed` like on FreeBSD's on which it is based, you need `-i ''` instead of `-i` for in-place editing. `sed` has `=` to report the line number but you can't make any manipulation on it like embed it in a string. It's also not reset between files in POSIX-compliant `sed` implementations (in the case of GNU `sed`, it's reset when using the `-i` or `-s` non-standard options).

Note that it will edit (and replace) every `.myfile` file even those that don't contain `abc`. You could work around that with:

```
find . -name '*.myfile' -type f -exec grep -l --null abc {} + |
  xargs -0 perl -i -pe '
  chomp($was = $_);
  print STDERR "$ARGV($.): $was : $_" if s/abc/def/;
  close ARGV if eof' --
```

The `grep` on macos has an API based on some old version of GNU `grep` (as it used to have GNU `grep` or at least FreeBSD on which it is based used to) so you'll find some GNU options in there including that `--null` (though not the `-Z` short variant). Its `xargs` also has GNU's `-0` option but unfortunately not the `-r` option (yet), so you'll get an error by `perl` if `find` doesn't find any file.

If you don't want to modify the files in place and just print the matches and how they would be substituted, then that becomes:

```
find . -name '*.myfile' -type f -exec perl -nle '
  $was = $_;
  print "$ARGV($.): $was : $_" if s/abc/def/;
  close ARGV if eof' -- {} +
```

No `-i`nplace, `-n` to `n`ot `p`rint the line at the end of each cycle; `-l` does the `chomp` on `$_` automatically (and `print` is told to add a `\n` on output). We print on stdout instead of stderr (redirect the whole command to stderr with `>&2` is you want it to go to stderr instead; at the prompt of an interactive shell in a terminal, both stdout and stderr should go to the terminal so it shouldn't make a difference).

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you so much. One last question, if I want to make this non-recursive, what do I do? I assumed the "{} +" is the recursive notation, and I removed it, but I got an error.

Comment: @Susie, no it's not. Rather than assuming, you could read the manual of your `find` implementation. To stop `find` from descending into a directory you need to call `-prune` on that director. So `find . ! -name . -prune -o -name '*.myfile' -type f -exec ....`. Some `find` implementations also support some `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` predicates. Here is you want the files at depth 1 (the children of the current directory) , that would be `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`.

Comment: Got it. Much appreciated. (I've been reading the manual for perl, still deciphering everything, thank you). :)